# Widget attribute does not work

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have two forms and a formset. I have given `__init__` for both the forms. However in my template only my POBodyForm is rendered with the attributes. Looks like `__init__` of POHeaderForm is not working. I am not sure what is the error. Can someone please advise?

I have been using the similar `__init__` class all over my project and this the first time a form is refusing to render or causing me an issue.
[image]
Relevant Form Code:

```
class POHeaderForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = POHeaderModel
    fields = '__all__'

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(POHeaderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in self.fields:
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}


class POBodyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = POBodyModel
        fields = '__all__'
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(POBodyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in self.fields:
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs = {'class': 'form-control form-control-sm'}

POFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(POHeaderModel, POBodyModel,form=POBodyForm, extra=1)
```

and the view is as follows:

```
class PurchaseOrderCBV(CreateView):
    model = POHeaderModel
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('purchase_order')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(PurchaseOrderCBV, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['formbody'] = POFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['formbody'] = POFormSet()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formbody = context['formbody']
        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if formbody.is_valid():
                formbody.instance = self.object
                formbody.save()
        return super(PurchaseOrderCBV, self).form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out the exact cause of this. I figured that my issue was with the view, My view was overriding the `init` method for some reason. I shifted from class-based view to function based view and it works pretty well. This is not an exact solution but a workaround with the alternate option available. As it does my work.

[image]